# Looking for GSview for OSX

Tags: postscript

Does anyone know where I can find a copy of [GSview](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/get50.htm) that will run on OSX?

I have already tried the following:

- I searched for a Homebrew recipe for GSview, but I didn't find one.  (BTW, I already have the `ghostscript-9.05` recipe installed; AFAICT, this recipe did not include GSview.)
- I downloaded a copy of `MacGSView_2.0b3_Installer.bin`, but when I click on it, an error message tells me that it can't be opened because "the Classic environment is no longer supported."
- I downloaded the [source code](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/download/gsv50src.zip), hoping to be able to build the executable, but AFAICT the download does not include any instructions or scripts for installing under OS X (or even under Unix).  More precisely, the little Unix-oriented information I was able to find in the download seems to be entirely obsolete, since it mentions files names that do not remotely resemble the files in the downloaded zip file, etc.  (A set of instructions for building and installing the app from the contents of this download would be an entirely acceptable answer to this question.)
- all the hits I get when I Google for `GSview OSX`, even those that include the string "OSX" or "OS X" in the title, are actually for Windows executables.

Comment: Why do you need a PS viewer when Preview can display PS files?

Comment: @Ihf http://stackoverflow.com/q/6614207/54964 There is loss of data when viewing with Preview, I think. Also *Unlike Apple's Preview program, MacGhostView does not convert Postscript files to PDF format and then display the PDF file.*

Answer (score 6):

You could try MacGhostView:

http://www.kiffe.com/macghostview.html

If you have Mountain Lion, you will also have to install XQuartz:

http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Comment: MacGhostView 5.0 from http://www.kiffe.com/macghostview.html seems to work fine for me.